# keyListener and thread not working

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

Hey I'm trying to have the console print out "holding" when a key is being held. I'm using an applet
because this code is to test key holding in applets. if any someone with good java knowledge can explain to me whats going on it will be much appreciated.

I'm pretty sure that the problem might have something to do with the thread.

```
public class appletkeytest extends Applet implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    boolean held;

    public void init(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        Thread t = new Thread( this );
        t.start();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        held = true;
        System.out.println(held);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
        held = false;
        System.out.println(held);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(held);

        while(held){
            System.out.println("holding");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(held)` should be `while(true)` and you might need to break the loop with additional condition. Whats happening here, the `run` method already executed before you even press the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd advise defining `held` as volatile.

Second, since you start the thread from the `init()` method, it will start running before you ever pressed the key, and thus finish right away.

I'd leave `init` like this:

```
public void init() {
    addKeyListener(this);
}
```

And change the `keyPressed` listener to:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    boolean wasHeld = held;
    held = true;
    System.out.println(held);
    if ( !wasHeld) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

The reasoning behind the `wasHeld` variable is that when you hold down a key, it actually sends multiple `keyPressed` events until it is released. If you just created a thread for each of these, you'll have many threads created during one key holding, all of them busily writing to your console.

So you want to create the thread only if this is the first time the `keyPressed` event was sent for this particular key press. A new thread will be created when you press a key again after releasing the previous one.

Comment: I would add `requestFocus()` to the `init` method... I don't know if this differs from IDE to IDE or whatever, but I have to click the applet first to give it focus so that things can happen; adding that would automatically give it focus.

Comment: @TNT - doesn't work for me. It could be Eclipse or MacOS X, but at `init()` the Applet is not visible yet, and therefore `requestFocus()` fails.